# Using phpunit in laravel 4 without /vendor/bin/

Tags: cmd, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

I have installed phpunit in this instance of laravel using composer.  The files are present in the laravel/vendor/bin folder.  when I run vendor/bin/phpunit the example test runs.  In all the tutorials I am watching on unit testing in laravel the tutors simply run phpunit and it runs the test.

In the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/testing) it says that I should be able to simply run phpunit to initiate the tests.

Is the documentation refering to phpunit being installed system wide and do the tutors in the video simply have it installed system wide or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have it installed system wide.

If you are in Windows, you can modify your PATH system variable to include the path to phpunit.  For example on mine, I've appended `;C:\wamp\www\rel\vendor\bin` to it.

Then you'd just have to navigate to the folder your project is in which should have the `phpunit.xml` file that was included with laravel and run `phpunit` on your command prompt.

Unfortunately, I am not completely sure how to do this on Linux or OSX.

Comment: Thanks, I am on windows and I tried to install phpunit globally via composer and the command line using this command composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*'[link](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html)  but I get a composer error telling me that it cannot parse the version string

Comment: Try using `composer global require` and then when it says `Search for a package[]:`, type `phpunit/phpunit`.  It will usually be the `0` choice, so just type `0` and enter and just answer each of the questions.  If you aren't sure, if you just push `enter`, it will decide best choice for you, usually.  Then run `composer update` again and you should be good to go as long as you have your PATH variable setup previously as described.  You may also want to look into http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/ for the color coding on the command prompt.

Comment: that seems to have worked as far as installing it globally however I dont seem to have the path correct as I still get the not recognized error, this is what I added to my path 'C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin;'

Comment: I got it thanks to correct path was C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\bin

Answer (score 6):

In linux, get phpunit path by typing `which phpunit` in the terminal. Its probably in the /usr/bin/ dir. execute

```
alias phpunit='/usr/bin/phpunit'
```

in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS, just go to your Laravel project directory via Terminal and then enter this command:

```
alias phpunit="~/Your Project Directory Name/vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

From now on you can run PHPUnit by just simply typing `phpunit`.